# Blur HTML5 canvas issue

Tags: javascript, canvas, opengl-es, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

The canvas does not allow me to use other domain URLs and show a cross-domain error.

I have to use this demo https://tympanus.net/Development/FlowmapDeformation/index3.html but I face some issues on the frontend.

At the front end of the demo, it shows blurs SVG image in the canvas.

**Demo use below Vertex and fragment:**

```
const vertex = `
    attribute vec2 uv;
    attribute vec2 position;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    void main() {
        vUv = uv;
        gl_Position = vec4(position, 0, 1);
    }
`;
const fragment = `
    precision highp float;
    precision highp int;
    uniform sampler2D tWater;
    uniform sampler2D tFlow;
    uniform float uTime;
    varying vec2 vUv;
    uniform vec4 res;

    void main() {
        // R and G values are velocity in the x and y direction
        // B value is the velocity length
        vec3 flow = texture2D(tFlow, vUv).rgb;

        vec2 uv = .5 * gl_FragCoord.xy / res.xy ;

        vec2 myUV = (uv - vec2(0.5))*res.zw + vec2(0.5);
        myUV -= flow.xy * (0.15 * 0.5);
        vec3 tex = texture2D(tWater, myUV).rgb;

        gl_FragColor.rgb = vec3(tex.r, tex.g, tex.b);
        gl_FragColor.a = tex.r;
    }
`;
```

**SVG image code:**

```
let imgSize = [1600, 1200];
const img = new Image();
img.onload = () => (texture.image = img);
img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";

img.src = "img/Alienation.svg";

const program = new Program(gl, {
    vertex,
    fragment,
    uniforms: {
      uTime: { value: 0 },
      tWater: { value: texture },
      res: {
        value: new ogl.Vec4(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight)
      },
      img: { value: new ogl.Vec2(imgSize[0], imgSize[1]) },
      tFlow: flowmap.uniform
    }
  });
```

See the original SVG image - https://tympanus.net/Development/FlowmapDeformation/img/Alienation.svg

Check the attached screenshot for more information.

[image]

Comment: OpenGL doesn't work with vector graphics, just with pixel graphics. How do you get the svg into the OpenGL texture? It's unclear if the blurring comes from the shader or from the SVG -> pixel conversion.

Comment: @BDL updated the question please check now